# SQL query to that limits only a subset of the records

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table of people, with rows `name`, `gender (M/F)`, and `age`.

What would a SQL query look like that returns:

- all female people
- a maximum of 5 male people
- people sorted by age

NB. This is a contrived example. Also, Postgres-specific answers welcome.

Comment: you mean a single query that would do all that together? like a `UNION` product of all female people and top 5 male people cross-sorted by age?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT name, gender, age
  FROM ( SELECT name, gender, age
           FROM people
           WHERE gender = 'F'
         UNION ALL
         ( SELECT name, gender, age
             FROM people
             WHERE gender = 'M'
             LIMIT 5  
         )
       ) x
  ORDER BY age
```

Note the above solution doesn't pick any particular males. Apply an ordering to the male subquery if you want that.

This one orders the males by age before the pruning takes place:

```
SELECT name, gender, age
  FROM ( SELECT name, gender, age
               ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY gender ORDER BY age) gender_count
           FROM people
        ) x
   WHERE gender = 'F'
      OR gender_count <= 5
```

BTW, I've found "gender" is usually used for grammatical references. In this case "sex" would have been the terminology I would have used.

Comment: Minor improvement: [`UNION ALL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION) instead of `UNION`.